# how to remove .0 or E in Result or stop crashes if using integer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

I am using edittexts with a textview when edittext get numbers textview show result but when I used Integer edt crashes after 10 digits. then I used double but now it is showing .0 in textview and also E between result

I have already tried each and every possible answer from stackoverflow but not succeeded in my case.

here is my activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_catering);

    edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.starters);
    edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.breakfast);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    edt1.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
    edt2.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Expences", MODE_PRIVATE);

    tv.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("exp","hello"));

    edt1.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("edt1","5"));

    edt2.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("edt2","5"));
}

public TextWatcher mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        tv.setText(addNumbers());

        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.putString("exp", addNumbers());
        edit.apply();
        tv.setText( addNumbers());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
};

private String addNumbers() {
    double number1;
    double number2;

    if (edt1.getText().toString() != "" && edt1.getText().length() > 0) {
        number1 = Double.parseDouble(edt1.getText().toString());

        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.putString("edt1", "5");
        edit.commit();
    } else {
        number1 = 0;
    }

    if (edt2.getText().toString() != "" && edt2.getText().length() > 0) {
        number2 = Double.parseDouble(edt2.getText().toString());
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.putString("edt2", "5");
        edit.commit();
    } else {
        number2 = 0;
    }
    return Double.toString(number1 + number2);
}
```

I have already tried this but app crashes when I enter 9 digits in edit text

```
 private String addNumbers() {
    int number1;
    int number2;
    if (edt1.getText().toString() != "" && edt1.getText().length() > 0) {
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(edt1.getText().toString());


        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.putString("edt1", "5");
        edit.commit();

    } else {
        number1 = 0;
    }
    if (edt2.getText().toString() != "" && edt2.getText().length() > 0) {
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(edt2.getText().toString());
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.putString("edt2", "5");
        edit.commit();
    } else {
        number2 = 0;
    }

    return Integer.toString(number1 + number2);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is crashing because an `Integer` data type has its limits. You should use `Long` data type instead of `Integer`. In Java, an int only ranges from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Whereas a long data type ranges from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. These values can be found using `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Similarly for `Long`, `Long.MAX_VALUE` and `Long.MIN_VALUE`.

Also, when you want to check if a `String` is empty in java, you should use the built-in method `.isEmpty()`. So in your case, your if-statements would be simplified from `if (edt1.getText().toString() != "" && edt1.getText().length() > 0)` to `if (!edt1.getText().toString().isEmpty())`

Moreover, whenever you do a string comparison, you should use Java's built in method `.equals(...)`. For example, `stringOne.equals(stringTwo);` instead of using `==` or `!=` operators. See this link for explanation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/

Comment: I just want to stop app crashing when typing edittext no matter if 9 digits

Comment: when I type long it is getting 19 digits but still activity crashes if limit is more than it

Answer (score 0):

To avoid crash, take the value as a string from the EditText and then store it into array. And then perform your desired operations on those arrays. 
Check this [link](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-two-large-numbers/amp/) for more detail.

Edit: try this in your activity file.

```
//in MainActivity.java, call like this
String val1 = edittext1.getText().toString() 
String val2 = edittext2.getText().toString() 
String result = fundSum(val1, val2) 

//function to calculate sum for big numbers
public String findSum(String str1, String str2)  
{  

    // Before proceeding further, make sure length  

    // of str2 is larger.  

    if (str1.length() > str2.length()){  

        String t = str1; 

        str1 = str2; 

        str2 = t; 

    } 



    // Take an empty String for storing result  

    String str = "";  



    // Calculate length of both String  

    int n1 = str1.length(), n2 = str2.length();  



    // Reverse both of Strings 

    str1=new StringBuilder(str1).reverse().toString(); 

    str2=new StringBuilder(str2).reverse().toString(); 



    int carry = 0;  

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)  

    {  

        // Do school mathematics, compute sum of  

        // current digits and carry  

        int sum = ((int)(str1.charAt(i) - '0') +  

                    (int)(str2.charAt(i) - '0') + carry);  

        str += (char)(sum % 10 + '0');  



        // Calculate carry for next step  

        carry = sum / 10;  

    }  



    // Add remaining digits of larger number  

    for (int i = n1; i < n2; i++)  

    {  

        int sum = ((int)(str2.charAt(i) - '0') + carry);  

        str += (char)(sum % 10 + '0');  

        carry = sum / 10;  

    }  



    // Add remaining carry  

    if (carry > 0)  

        str += (char)(carry + '0');  



    // reverse resultant String 

    str = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString(); 



    return str;  
}
```

Comment: Can't understand can u please solve this according to my case...I am using Long.parseLong(edt6.getText().toString()); now but it is getting 19 digits and then again app crashes

Comment: Alok Bharti can u please tell me how can I take string and then store it into array in my case... I am new and don't know how to do it

Comment: Check the link, you can see explained solution and java code for this problem

Comment: unable to understand link..
I have tried this 
number6 = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(edt6.getText().toString().length()));

no more crashes but now calculation also stops